# C# Linq - Join 2 Lists, add in extra properties to existing List

Tags: c#, linq, list, join

Suppose I have the following 2 classes set up in my C# program:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string Var1;
    public string Var2;
    public string Var3;

    public string Var4;
    public string Var5;
}

public class Class2
{
    public string Var1;
    public string Var2;
    public string Var3;

    public string Var6;
    public string Var7;
}
```

---

And I have the following code in a method:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    List<Class1> Class1Data = GetClass1Data();
    List<Class2> Class2Data = GetClass2Data();

    var JoinedData = (from c1 in Class1Data
                        join c2 in Class2Data
                        on new
                        {
                            c1.Var1,
                            c1.Var2,
                            c1.Var3
                        }
                        equals new
                        {
                            c2.Var1,
                            c2.Var2,
                            c2.Var3
                        }
                        select new
                        {
                            c1.Var1,
                            c1.Var2,
                            c1.Var3,
                            c1.Var4,
                            c1.Var5,
                            c2.Var6,
                            c2.Var7
                        }).ToList();
}
```

Now, this does what I'd like, but, Ideally, I'd like to extend `Class1` to have the 2 extra fields - `Var6` and `Var7` and just have the results from `Class2` added onto my `Class1Data` list rather than create a new object with the joined data (trying to conserve memory rather than have 2 separate lists).

I'm sure this has been asked and answered many times before, but I just can't seem to find the best way to do this.

Thanks!!

Comment: Why not just keep a pair of references (c1 and c2)? Or are those objects going to be mutated? Is your memory concern because you know your solution *does* have aproblem, or are you worried that it *might* have a problem?

Comment: @JonSkeet, I'm a bit lost as to what you mean by keeping a pair of references - To explain a bit more, the first list returns a certain set of characteristics for an object and the second set a different set + the keys for matching the 2 sets, I'm just looking to merge all the characteristics into a single object and don't need to keep the original pulled data once I have that. Does that make sense?

Comment: Regarding memory, it doesn't have a problem, I just know that once I have the merged data, I don't need the two sets used to build it - I guess I could just as easily clear the 2 original lists.... Just wondering the best way to do this / build up good programming practices.

Comment: But why do you want a single object with the flattened properties? Why not just `new { c1, c2 }` then you can use `x.c1.var1` etc.

Comment: AAAAAH - Understood - Thank you @JonSkeet, that makes sense! Thank you!!

Comment: Well we need a lot more context to know what you're actually trying to do. If your anonymous type approach works, it's not clear that anything else will be more efficient. (You'll need to create a new object anyway, even if it's of a subclass...)